# Merge The same remote Git Branch into local Branch

Tags: git

I'm currently working on a jee project, using git.

my local workspace is linked to a git branch called "branch1". As I made multiple changes in my local workspace over a few days, without checking or verify the remote status of the branch1, someone acceseed the same remote branche while I was working locally and made change in the remote branch1.

my problem is how do I merge those changes into my local branch without losing anything ? 
PS: i've already tried merging, but git asks to commit the changes before the merge, which is not good.

Comment: Well, git is still right, you should try to avoid working for a few days without committing because you're going to get into situations like this. So get to a stable state for your branch (whatever that means for your situation), and make the commit, then do the merge.

Comment: fetch the remote branch. Compare the changes and you can take the needed changes

Comment: If you're completely unable to reach that state, you *could* try to stash all your changes, then revert them, then merge the branch, then apply the stashed commit. The problem now is if this ends up giving you a merge conflict then you're in a bit of a pickle. Again, you should try to avoid getting into this situation in the first place.

Comment: Make a **complete** backup of your local repository, working folder and all, then do `git stash`, then try to fetch/pull/merge, then `git stash apply`, see if that works. If it doesn't, then restore from backup and try something else.

Comment: if you commit in your local branch1:check "rebase --soft "documentation to uncommit them and bring them back into staging area and HEAD to desired place.then pull origin branch1 and then commit staged files.